# When and Where to call API in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

I am implementing flutter application which contain three tabs and in this app I am using bloc pattern the blocks are contain API calls and streams.

Now API calls are made in constructor of block class.

```
class FeedListingBlock extends BlocBase {

  String _category;

  PublishSubject<FeedResponse> _feedListingController =
  PublishSubject<FeedResponse>();
  Sink<FeedResponse> get feedListing => _feedListingController.sink;
  Stream<FeedResponse> get feedListingStream => _feedListingController.stream;

  void getFeedList(String filter, String page) {
    getFeeds(_category, page, filter).then((feedResponse) {
      feedListing.add(feedResponse);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _feedListingController.close();
  }

  FeedListingBlock(this._category) {
    getFeedList('All', '1');
  }

}
```

I have three tabs so it will create three instance of `FeedListingBlock` and I have `StreamWidgets` to listen the stream.

If I do like this it will make a API Call every time when state of home screen will changed because of that it will redraw the tabs.

So where to call the API when we are using `TabBarView` like widgets?

whether we have to call API in `initState` or `build` method?

Comment: "I have three tabs so it will create three instance of FeedListingBlock and I have StreamWidgets to listen the stream." - this is probably your problem. I suppose that you should init your bloc once in your home screen (may be in build(), but make sure it isn't initiated - if (bloc == null) init()) and pass it to tabbar widgets through the constructor. Then in your tabbar widgets you will have an initiated bloc and you could use it in your StreamBuilder.